# Blackberry - Sorting with accents

Tags: sorting, blackberry, vector

I am trying to sort a SimpleSortingVector in BlackBerry that contains french accents. The sorting puts the items with accents at the very end of the list. How do I sort in blackberry that will put the accented characters with unaccented characters. Collator doesn't seem to work because I believe I am building for too low of a JRE version. I'm building for JRE 4.5.0 minimum.

ie

É = E

here is how I sort the vector:

```
ssv.setSortComparator(new Comparator()
{
     public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2)
     {
          String value = ((Item) obj1).getText();
          String otherValue = ((Item) obj2).getText();

          return value.compareTo(otherValue);
     }
});

ssv.reSort();
```

Thanks,
DMan

Answer (score 2):

OS 4.5 is a challenge.  For OS 7, RIM added a string comparer to [StringUtilities](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/StringUtilities.html) that can be configured the way you want:

```
StringUtilities.compare(String aString1, int aOffset1, int aLength1,
                        String aString2, int aOffset2, int aLength2,
                        int aLevel, int aLocale, int aFlags, int aFlagsMask)
```

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any built-in solutions for earlier versions of BBOS.  You can build your own sorting table for French characters, and write a custom comparer if you only need to support French. If you're looking for global compatibility, that will get tedious though.